# Vaadin: How do I get rid of the grey "Upload" box to the right of the "browse" box?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

```
Upload upload = new Upload("My File");
addComponent(upload);
```

[image]

I want that gone because I have a nice one on the line below. 
Thanks community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
upload.setButtonCaption(null);
```